# understanding structure function *adds and rel_list

Tags: c, pointers, struct, structure

I am trying to understand what the `*adds` part of this function does:

Comment: you should make yourself familiar with function signatures, pointers and pointers to functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should read more about `pointers`

---

`*adds` in this `*` is not associated with `adds` but with the return type.

It is more like this..

```
struct list* adds(struct data *head, void fun)
```

Now it is easy to make out that `adds` is a function that returns a `pointer to struct list`.

---

This is the way of declaring a `pointer to a function`

```
void (*free_fun)(void *)
```

Start reading from the name `free_fun`. free_fun is a `*`, so `pointer`, to a function, that take arguments `(void *)` and returns `void`.

Answer (score 0):

The adds function returns a pointer to a struct of type list.

The rel_list function does not return anything.

free_fun is a pointer to a function that does not return anything.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! What does the *free_fun do in the second function? Is it a pointer to a struct of type rel_list?

Answer (score 0):

`struct list *adds(struct data *head, void fun)` is a function called `adds` that returns a pointer to a `struct` of type `list`.

`void rel_list(struct data *dta, void (*free_fun)(void *))` is a function that takes a `struct` of type `data` and a function pointer with the prototype `void something(void *in)`